# Multiple group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have one result query by doing union

Table A:

```
ItemNumber    CountRows
xxxxxxxx        12
yyyyyyyy        18
xxxxxxxxx       10
yyyyyyyyy       9
```

the result what I'm looking for is :

```
ItemNumber     CountRows    CountTest
xxxxxxxxx       12            10
yyyyyyyyy       18            9
```

Thanks,

Aissam.

Comment: This is a basic `join`.  What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: sorry i change it this is my needs

Comment: Not only did you change the question to something that is equally inscrutable, but you also invalidated answers to the first version of the question.  I'm voting to close this question.  I would suggest you ask another question, and be clearer on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select t1.ItemNumber,t1.CountRows,t2.CountTest
from TableA t1, TableB t2
WHERE t1.ItemNumber=t2.ItemNumber
```

Comment: my table is selection query

Answer (score 1):

This is the most basic join in SQL, in the future - please avoid asking questions like this before making attempts to solve this on your own.

```
SELECT A.item_number,a.countRow,b.countTest
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON (A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber)
```

You can read about [SQL JOINS here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).